# Unable to change input field text content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to change the text inside an input field to username.
The id for the field is is_username.

And in my Javascript file I've tried

```
document.getElementById("id_username").innerHTML = "Username";

document.getElementById("id_username").value = "Username";

document.querySelector(".id_username").textContent = "Username";
```

None are working... This site runs on django.
I know with html you can use placeholder to achieve this but these fields are created using django tags.

Any ideas?

I did try using these methods on a normal html input field and also had no luck.

htmlpage:

```
{% extends 'display_words.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="display-box">
            <!-- <p>Please login to see this page.</p> -->
          {% if form.errors %}
            <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
          {% endif %}

          {% if next %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
              please login with an account that has access.</p>
            {% else %}
              <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}

          <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
              <tr>
                <!-- <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td> -->
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!-- <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td> -->
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input id="login-button" class="button" type="submit" value="login">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
          </form>

          {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
          <p id="lost-password-link"><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>
        </div>  
      </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I created a test html file and it also doesn't work: code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Words & Phrases</title>

    
  </head>

  <body>

    <input type="text" id=“id_username”>

<script>

    document.querySelector('#id_username').textContent = 'username';

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: can you share Html content? this should work
`document.getElementById("id_username").value = "Username";`

Comment: it didn't work. I've added the html

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="id_username"]').value = 'Username';
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id_username" id="id_username" placeholder="Your text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to point out that when you tried your queryselector. You used ".id_username", this selects a class that is called that, not the id.

You can try to store the selected element in a variable then, run the innerHTML/textcontent.

```
const stubbornInput = document.getElementById("id_username");

stubbornInput.innerHTML = 'Whatever you want';
```

Ive had cases where this worked but, going straight for the thing didnt. Not sure if it helps or why it worked for me before but, worth a shot :)

Comment: no luck :( thanks though

Comment: Not familiar with django but, looking at your html I have another idea. Just try to right click on google chrome preview onto the input, see if it actually does have the id="id_username".

If it does, possibly the code selecting it runs before the html gets compiled? Not sure how django works so maybe Im talking bs. But you could wrap your js in 

window.onload = () => {
  // add the js here
};

This would ensure that the js runs after everything is loaded, aka html is compiled if thats even how django works. Farting bubbles here but trying to help lol

Comment: i checked before. it definitely has id="id_username" in the browser html. ill give the suggestion a shot.

Comment: didn't work :'( thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

your text input has the ID `username`, in your javascript it says `id_username` try this input and the javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("username").value = "your_value_here";
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

If that doesn't work, try using JQuery.

```
$("input[name=username]").val("hello_world")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok below is the correct answer:

my main js file was causing an issue which is why it didn't work for me earlier. After i created a empty js file for this purpose it worked.

```
document.querySelector('#id_username').value = 'username' ;
document.querySelector('#id_username').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('#id_username').value = '';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier was to do this:

document.querySelector('#id_username').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Username');